# How to change text in textbox when I press the button?

Tags: c#

Frist of all, I'm a beginner in C# and I want to become a game dev one day. So here I am! Asking about this simple question for you, but not for me.

The question is, I wanted my code to change text when I press the button. Imagine you're playing text-based adventure game which I'm trying to make here, and when you press the button it'll change the text each time when you press it.

But my code doesn't, here is my code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkFcI.png)

The code is not wrong, but it doesn't work as I expected. It'll show only the last one but not from the first to last.

If you can help me develop my knowledge about this I'd be thankful so much.

Comment: Thank you Mr. John for answering my question, Maybe I don't get your hint, but if I understand it right, I don't want to cycle my messages. I want players or users press the button to continue reading the text line by line.

Like when you're reading a novel and you have to read it through each line to understand the story. That's how I want it to be.

Thank you again Mr. John for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can cycle through an `array` or a `List`.

Here is a very simple exemple:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TextLineByLine
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<string> Messages = new List<string>();
        int currentLine = -1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Add some messages
            Messages.Add("You open your eyes");
            Messages.Add("The bright blue sky is up there");
            Messages.Add("And some blood covers the ground");
            Messages.Add("You're not sure what happened...");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currentLine++; // increment the line index
            if (currentLine < Messages.Count)
            {
                Title.Text = Messages[currentLine];
            }
            else
            {
                Title.Text = "-= Nothing to display =-";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. StringBuilder, I'll try your code out and study it in case. Thank you for helping me develop my coding knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question well you want a text change each time it is pressed.

You can do it easily by using an Integer for example.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{
    int dialogue = 0;
    public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }
    private void btnAction_Clickl(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        switch ( dialogue ) 
        {
            case 0:
                Title.Text = "Some text";
                dialogue++;
                break;
            case 1:
                Title.Text = "Another text";
                dialogue++;
                break;
            default: //just in case you want to reset the text
                Title.Text = "First text";
                dialogue = 0;
                break;
         }
    }
}
```

If you want to set it automatic, like just one click and then the text changes every x seconds you can use:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{
    public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }
    private void btnAction_Clickl(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        Dialogue();
    }
    
    private async void Dialogue()
    {
        Title.Text = "Some text";
        await Task.Delay(2000); // Where 2000 means 2 seconds in milliseconds
        Title.Text = "More text"; // And so on...
    }
}
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is not going to behave how you expect in this context. This will sleep the main UI thread of the WPF application and cause the entire UI to become unresponsive.

Comment: You're right, didn't think of it at the moment I wrote it, my bad.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Tsetsi, I've already tried your code and it work perfectly! Thank you for sharing coding knowledge to me and hopefully to another beginners who may have the same problem with mine. 

Again, thank you for helping me develop my knowledge in coding.

Comment: You're welcome ^^. If your problem has been solved feel free to mark it as solved so others can see it clearly. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create a string array for your sentences like this and do the following.

```
int counter = 0;

private void btnAction_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] messages = new string[4]
    messages[0] = "Your first message";
    messages[1] = "Your second message";
    messages[2] = "Your third message";
    messages[3] = "Your fourth message";
    
    title.Text = messages[0];
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Mr. Andrei, I'll try your code out and study it in case. Thank you for helping me develop my knowledge in coding.